# Unable to Call the balanceOf() function from web3 using the input wallet address

Tags: solidity, web3js

This is my web3js and html code for frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Balance Checker</title>

<script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script> 

</head> <body>
<h1 id="display"></h1>
<input id="wallet_add" type="text">
<button id="button">Check Balance</button> 




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>


    <script>

        if(typeof web3!== 'undefined'){



web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

     }else 

   web3 = new Web3(new 
   Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

    var P1Contract =  web3.eth.contract([   {       "constant": false,      "inputs": [

            {
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "name": "value", 
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "name": "approve",      "outputs": [            {
                "name": "ok",
                "type": "bool"          }       ],      "payable": false,       "stateMutability": "nonpayable",        "type": "function"  },  {       "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],       "name": "totalSupply",      "outputs": [            {
                "name": "total_Supply",
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "payable": false,       "stateMutability": "view",      "type": "function"  },  {       "constant":
false,      "inputs": [             {
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "name": "value", 
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "name": "transferFrom",         "outputs": [            {
                "name": "ok", 
                "type": "bool"          }       ],      "payable": false,       "stateMutability": "nonpayable",        "type": "function"  },  {       "constant": true,
        "inputs": [             {
                "name": "who",
                "type": "address"           }       ],      "name": "balanceOf",        "outputs": [            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "payable": false,       "stateMutability": "view",      "type": "function"  },  {       "constant":
false,      "inputs": [             {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "name": "value", 
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "name": "transfer",         "outputs": [            {
                "name": "ok",
                "type": "bool"          }       ],      "payable": false,       "stateMutability": "nonpayable",        "type": "function"  },  {       "constant": true,       "inputs": [             {
                "name": "owner",        
        "type": "address"           },          {
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"           }       ],      "name": "allowance",        "outputs": [            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "payable": false,       "stateMutability": "view",      "type": "function"  },  {       "anonymous": false,         "inputs": [             {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "name": "Transfer",         "type": "event"     },  {       "anonymous": false,         "inputs": [             {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"           },          {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"           }       ],      "name": "Approval",         "type": "event"     } ]);

        var P1 = P1Contract.at('0xf5dd801d32ea5864316066b440f7149d5d9f268f');

        console.log(P1);


        $('#button').click(function(){

       P1.balanceOf($('#wallet_add').val(),(err,res) =>{

   if(err){
       console.log('Oh no');    }else{    $('#display').html(result[0]);    }   } );

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my backend code for smart contract

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19; 
 /**  * @title SafeMath  * @dev Math operations with safety checks that
 throw on error  */ library SafeMath {

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) { 
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
         uint256 c = a / b;
         // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
         return c;
     }


    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }


    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    } }

contract ERC20 { 

     function totalSupply()public view returns (uint total_Supply);
    function balanceOf(address who)public view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender)public view returns (uint);
     function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value)public returns (bool ok);
     function approve(address spender, uint value)public returns (bool ok);

   function transfer(address to, uint value)public returns (bool ok);

     event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
     event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

 }

 contract FiatContract {
     function USD(uint _id) constant returns (uint256); }


contract P1 is ERC20 { 
    using SafeMath for uint256;


   FiatContract price = FiatContract(0x8055d0504666e2B6942BeB8D6014c964658Ca591); // MAINNET ADDRESS

     // Name of the token
     string public constant name = "P1";
     // Symbol of token
     string public constant symbol = "P1";
     uint8 public constant decimals = 8;
     uint public _totalsupply = 1000000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);
     address public owner;
     bool stopped = false;
     uint256 public startdate;
     uint256 ico_first;
     uint256 ico_second;
     uint256 ico_third;

 uint256 ico_fourth;
 address central_account;
 mapping(address => uint) balances;
 mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


 enum Stages {
     NOTSTARTED,
     ICO,
     PAUSED,
     ENDED
 }

 Stages public stage;

 modifier atStage(Stages _stage) {
     if (stage != _stage)
         // Contract not in expected state
         revert();
     _;
 }
```

> ```
> modifier onlyOwner() {
>     if (msg.sender != owner) {
>         revert();
>     }
>     _;
> }
>
> modifier onlycentralAccount {
>     require(msg.sender == central_account);
>     _;
> }
>
> function P1() public
> {
>     owner = msg.sender;
>     balances[owner] = 350000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);
>     balances[address(this)] = 650000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);
>     stage = Stages.NOTSTARTED;
>     Transfer(0, owner, balances[owner]);
>     Transfer(0, address(this), balances[address(this)]);
> }
>
> function () public payable atStage(Stages.ICO)
> {
>     require(msg.value >= 1 finney); //for round up and security measures
>     require(!stopped && msg.sender != owner);
>
>     uint256 ethCent = price.USD(0); //one USD cent in wei
>     uint256 tokPrice = ethCent.mul(14); 
>
>     tokPrice = tokPrice.div(10 ** 8); //limit to 10 places
>     uint256 no_of_tokens = msg.value.div(tokPrice);
>
>     uint256 bonus_token = 0;
>
>     // Determine the bonus based on the time and the purchased amount
>     if (now < ico_first)
>     {
>         if (no_of_tokens >=  2000 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>             no_of_tokens <= 19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(50).div(100); // 50% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >   19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>                  no_of_tokens <= 149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(55).div(100); // 55% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens > 149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(60).div(100); // 60% bonus
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(45).div(100); // 45% bonus
>         }
>     }
>     else if (now >= ico_first && now < ico_second)
>     {
>         if (no_of_tokens >=  2000 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>             no_of_tokens <= 19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(40).div(100); // 40% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >   19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>                  no_of_tokens <= 149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(45).div(100); // 45% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >  149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(50).div(100); // 50% bonus
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(35).div(100); // 35% bonus
>         }
>     }
>     else if (now >= ico_second && now < ico_third)
>     {
>         if (no_of_tokens >=  2000 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>             no_of_tokens <= 19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(30).div(100); // 30% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >   19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>                  no_of_tokens <= 149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(35).div(100); // 35% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >  149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(40).div(100); // 40% bonus
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(25).div(100); // 25% bonus
>         }
>     }
>     else if (now >= ico_third && now < ico_fourth)
>     {
>         if (no_of_tokens >=  2000 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>             no_of_tokens <= 19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(20).div(100); // 20% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >   19999 * (uint256(10)**decimals) &&
>                  no_of_tokens <= 149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(25).div(100); // 25% bonus
>         }
>         else if (no_of_tokens >  149999 * (uint256(10)**decimals))
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(30).div(100); // 30% bonus
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             bonus_token = no_of_tokens.mul(15).div(100); // 15% bonus
>         }
>     }
>       uint256 total_token = no_of_tokens + bonus_token;
>     this.transfer(msg.sender, total_token);
> }
>
> function start_ICO() public onlyOwner atStage(Stages.NOTSTARTED) {
>
>     stage = Stages.ICO;
>     stopped = false;
>     startdate = now;
>     ico_first = now + 14 days;
>     ico_second = ico_first + 14 days;
>     ico_third = ico_second + 14 days;
>     ico_fourth = ico_third + 14 days;
>
> }
>
> // called by the owner, pause ICO
> function StopICO() external onlyOwner atStage(Stages.ICO) {
>
>     stopped = true;
>     stage = Stages.PAUSED;
>
> }
>
> // called by the owner , resumes ICO
> function releaseICO() external onlyOwner atStage(Stages.PAUSED) {
>
>     stopped = false;
>     stage = Stages.ICO;
>
> }
>
> function end_ICO() external onlyOwner atStage(Stages.ICO) {
>
>     require(now > ico_fourth);
>     stage = Stages.ENDED;
>
> }
>
> function burn(uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner
> {
>     require(_amount <= balances[address(this)]);
>
>     _totalsupply = _totalsupply.sub(_amount);
>     balances[address(this)] = balances[address(this)].sub(_amount);
>     balances[0x0] = balances[0x0].add(_amount);
>     Transfer(address(this), 0x0, _amount);
> }
>
> function set_centralAccount(address central_Acccount) external onlyOwner {
>
>     central_account = central_Acccount;
>
> }
>
>
>
> function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256 total_Supply) {
>
>     total_Supply = _totalsupply;
>
> }
>
> // What is the balance of a particular account?
> function balanceOf(address _owner)public view returns (uint256 balance) {
>
>     return balances[_owner];
>
> }
>
> // Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
> // The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
> // tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
> // fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
> // deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
> // these standardized APIs for approval:
> function transferFrom( address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount )public returns (bool success) {
>
>     require( _to != 0x0);
>
>     balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_amount);
>     allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
>     balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
>
>     Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
>
>     return true;
> }
>
> // Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
> // If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
> function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount)public returns (bool success) {
>     require(_amount == 0 || allowed[msg.sender][_spender] == 0);
>     require( _spender != 0x0);
>
>     allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _amount;
>
>     Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _amount);
>
>     return true;
> }
>
> function allowance(address _owner, address _spender)public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
>
>     require( _owner != 0x0 && _spender !=0x0);
>
>     return allowed[_owner][_spender];
>    }
>
> // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account
> function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount)public returns (bool success) {
>
>     require( _to != 0x0);
>
>     balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
>     balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
>
>     Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
>
>     return true;
> }
>
> function transferby(address _from,address _to,uint256 _amount) external onlycentralAccount returns(bool success) {
>
>     require( _to != 0x0);
>
>     // Only allow transferby() to transfer from 0x0 and the ICO account
>     require(_from == address(this));
>
>     balances[_from] = (balances[_from]).sub(_amount);
>      balances[_to] = (balances[_to]).add(_amount);
>      if (_from == 0x0)
>      {
>          _totalsupply = _totalsupply.add(_amount);
>      }
> ```

```
     Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);

     return true;
 }

 //In case the ownership needs to be transferred
 function transferOwnership(address newOwner)public onlyOwner {

     balances[newOwner] = balances[newOwner].add(balances[owner]);
     balances[owner] = 0;
     owner = newOwner;

 }

 function drain() external onlyOwner {

     owner.transfer(this.balance);

 }
  }
```

Kindly help me sort out this

Comment: To begin with, change `web3.eth.contract` to `web3.eth.Contract`.

Comment: no its web3.eth.contract only

Comment: If you're using web3.js, which I assume that you are (and recommend that you upgrade to if you're not), then it should be `Contract`, with a capital C.